# Azure DNS Resolver - ruleset VNet Links

Tags: azure, azure-dns

I'm testing out the DNS Resolver feature which is currently in preview. Works well so far, minus working with the rulesets.

I have a ruleset that points back to on-premises DNS server for corporate domain. The issue comes in due to the fact that you need to connect the rule to a VNet in order for it to be used as part of the resolution process. Documentation says that the ruleset and the VNet need to be within the same region... no problem there. The VNet is in a different subscription however. When setting the link, there is the option to select a different subscription and no errors occur during that part. When deploying however:

> Virtual Network Link add operation failed for
> AzureSC-Vnet-01-link: BadRequest -> Subscription
> for virtual network link is different than virtual network
> subscription.
> virtualNetworkLinkResourceId=/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/Dns-Rg/dnsForwardingRulesets/testrule/virtualNetworksLinks/vnet-link,
> virtualNetworkSubscriptionId=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx

It's complaining that the subscription IDs are different obviously. I'm assuming that this is a bug, not sure if anyone else has run into this.

Also, is there a GitHub repo where I can raise the issue? I can't seem to find out where to go. I've already opened a ticket but they're slow to respond.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the preview version does not support multi-subscription setups. Darn